# I want to run window cmd commands through perl from linux machine

Tags: linux, perl, cmd, window

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Net::Telnet;

$telnet = new Net::Telnet ( Timeout=>10,Errmode=>'die');
$telnet->open('hostname.domainname');
print "opened ...\n";
$telnet->waitfor('/login: $/i');
$telnet->print('pjpandey');
print "enetered username ...\n";
$telnet->waitfor('/password: $/i');
$telnet->print('pjp2213');
```

*I am getting this error

```
connecting to "hostname.domainname", port 23: Connection refused at ./login.pl line 6
```

I wanted to login window machine from a linux VM and rum the command(`java -jar selenium.jar`) in cmd through a perl script .
Can you please help me with a way other than telnet or any other scripting language ?
Thanks in advance !*

Comment: First, you probably don't want to have your username and password there. If nothing else, it shows everyone what sorts of passwords you use. Second, you probably don't have a telnet server running on the windows machine. If such a thing exists, you'll have to install it and make sure it's running. I can't help with that, though. Good luck, regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I do similar stuff RPC (remote procedure call).  Windows has horrible security track record with this.  You should consider instead of telnet use ssh.  With that you will find a great deal more support.

"How do you install run ssh on a windows box?" you ask?

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/41560/how-to-get-ssh-command-line-access-to-windows-7-using-cygwin/